# Change in temperature if salt is dissolved in water with different initial temperatures

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, enthalpy, heat

I will mix a salt with room-temperature water and 8 degree Celsius water. Then I will compare the heat of solution with each other.

Does the initial temperature of the water affect how much the heat of solution and change in temperature will be?

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Comment: I think the OP means to ask "Will the $\Delta T$ be different for a salt dissolved in water at two different temperatures?" which I think might be a helpful question.

Comment: You will find the answer of your question in the following article :
Nathalie Hubert, Roland Solimando, Alexandre Pere, Dissolution of NaCl at 25°C, 45°C, and 60°C. It was published in Thermodynamic Acta 294, No.2, Pages 157 - 161, July 1997, or under : https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-6031(97)00058-0 But this article is protected by a copyright.